# Which hg-git line should I remove from my .hgrc file?

Tags: git, mercurial

Whenever I do anything with mercurial (e.g. `hg status` in a repository folder) I get a message saying:

```
extension 'git' overrides commands: gclear git-cleanup gimport gverify gexport
```

and the relevant part of my `~/.hgrc` is:

```
[extensions]
hggit = 
hgext.git =
```

Removing any one of these two lines makes the message go away, but - which of these should I remove and which should I keep?

I use Devuan ASCII 2.0 (but this is not a distribution-generated `.hgrc` file). Package versions:

- mercurial 4.0-1+deb9u1
- mercurial-git 0.8.11-1
- git 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are including hg-git twice.

```
hggit =
```

Is the recommended way

```
hgext.git =
```

Is the older way to enable an extension and is available in mercurial just for backwards compatibility.

I would suggest using just the first.